# Произведение смежных чисел массива

Tags: java, android

решал алгоритм  и вот встала задача решить алгоритм на вход дается массив  чисел надо найти наибольшее произведение  смежных чисел
я решил так

```
public int maxProduct(int input[]) {
  int  maxProductValue= input[0]*input[1];
  for (int i =1 ; i<input.length;i++){
      if (maxProductValue<input[i]*input[i-1])
          maxProductValue=input[i]*input[i-1];
  }

  return maxProductValue;
}
```

все работает но чтото мне подсказывает что можно решить более красиво.Буду благодарен за решение

Comment: Так вопрос решен или нет?

Comment: Нет я все еще считаб свой подход медленным.и жду ответа

Comment: Как минимум произведение можно было бы считать один раз (с точки зрения красоты кода), и заменить `if` на  `maxProductValue = max(maxProductValue, input[i]*input[i-1]);`

Comment: и input[i-1] в локальную переменную сохранить с прошлой итерации